# How to choose one line from a file per day?

Tags: php

I will explain more

I have file called `date.php` and text file called `word.txt`. I put more Proverbs in `word.txt`

Now, every day I need to print one proverb only from `word.txt`, like this:

- Saturday prints "A burnt child dreads fire"
- Sunday prints "no gain without pain"
- and so on, the proverb will change every day

Can anyone help me with this idea?

Comment: Is it one proverb per calendar day, or per weekday?

Answer (score 7):

```
$proverbs = file('word.txt');
echo $proverbs[(int)date('z')%count($proverbs)];
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's a week rota (i.e. one proverb per weekday), I would do it like this:

```
$proverbs = array(

  # Monday 
  "Build a man a fire, and he'll be warm for a day.
   Set a man on fire, and he'll be warm for the rest of his life.
   -- Terry Pratchett", 

  # Tuesday
  "The pen is mightier than the sword if the sword is very short,
  and the pen is very sharp
  -- Terry Pratchett",

  # Wednesday
  "....",

  # Thursday
  "...."


  );

  $current_weekday = date("N"); # 1 = Monday ... 7 = Sunday

  echo $proverbs[$current_weekday];
```

Comment: but i need it in text not in array

Comment: Then load it into an array using php's file functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can read from a file using the [file function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).
Say you place the new proverb at the top, you can do something like this:

```
$lines = file('word.txt');
echo $lines[0]; // displays the first line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $proverbs = file('word.txt');
    $today = (int)date('N');
    echo $proverbs[$today - 1];
```

Just put all your proverbs on a new line in the text file.